# Kill process under specific user account with python

Tags: python, windows

I would like to kill an application (tree), e.g. MyApp.exe which is running under a specific user.
A process can be killed with:

```
os.system("taskkill /f /t /im  MyApp.exe")
```

However this doesn't kill the application for the user of interest!
The problem is that several users might be logged in and all running an instance of the same application! I don't want the application to be killed for the wrong user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need admin rights to see processes of all users.

```
import psutil

proc_name = 'calc.exe'
bad_users = [r'desktop\user1']

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name().lower() == proc_name \
    and proc.username().lower() in bad_users:
        print('kill', proc.pid)
        psutil.Process(proc.pid).kill()
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine as it is more flexible. It is probably possible to tweak my answer with "exec" to get this flexibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('taskkill /f /t /im MyApp.exe /fi "username eq my_user"')
```

shout out to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://serverfault.com/questions/536264/can-i-use-taskkill-to-kill-a-process-running-under-a-certain-user)